# Output multidimensional array into 3 columns div and ul li in php

Tags: php, html, multidimensional-array, foreach, while-loop

Here's an array : what I am trying to split the array into 3 column of divs with first array should be wrapped into a h3 tag then a other arrays should be displayed in an unordered list.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label_01] => heading 01:
            [label_02] => heading 02: 
            [label_03] => heading 03: 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label_01] => item 01
            [label_02] => item 02
            [label_03] => item 03
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [label_01] => item 001
            [label_02] => item 002
            [label_03] => item 003
        )

)
```

It should output like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h3 class="text-primary text-center">heading 01:</h3>
        <ul class="list-box">
            <li class="bg-primary text-white">item 01</li>
            <li class="bg-primary text-white">item 001</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h3 class="text-warning text-center">heading 02:</h3>
        <ul class="list-box">
            <li class="bg-warning text-white">item 02</li>
            <li class="bg-warning text-white">item 002</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h3 class="text-blue text-center">heading 03:</h3>
        <ul class="list-box">
            <li class="bg-blue text-white">item 03</li>
            <li class="bg-blue text-white">item 003</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried so far

```
<div class="row">
    <?php 
    $keys = array_keys($columns);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($columns); $i++) { ?>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
    <?php foreach($columns[$keys[$i]] as $key => $value) { ?>
            <li class="bg-primary text-white"><?php echo $value; ?></li>
    <?php } ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
            </div>
```

and this

```
<div class="row">
    <?php foreach ( $columns as $column ) { ?>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
            <h3 class="text-primary text-center">Inspire: Self Leadership</h3>
            <ul class="list-box">
        <?php foreach ($column as $val) { ?>
        <li class="bg-primary text-white"><?php echo $val; ?></li>
        
        <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a copy of that array and the power of PHP heredoc interpolation, you can do a little while loop. The copy is done to keep the original array intact. If you do not care, you can use `$data` directly.

```
$data = [
    [
        'label_01' => 'heading 01:',
        'label_02' => 'heading 02:',
        'label_03' => 'heading 03:'
    ],
    [
        'label_01' => 'item 01',
        'label_02' => 'item 02',
        'label_03' => 'item 03'
    ],
    [
        'label_01' => 'item 001',
        'label_02' => 'item 002',
        'label_03' => 'item 003'
    ]
];

echo '<div class="row">', PHP_EOL;
$copy = $data;
while(count($copy[0]))
{
    $h3  = array_shift($copy[0]);
    $li1 = array_shift($copy[1]);
    $li2 = array_shift($copy[2]);
    echo <<<"_HTML"
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h3 class="text-primary text-center">$h3</h3>
        <ul class="list-box">
            <li class="bg-primary text-white">$li1</li>
            <li class="bg-primary text-white">$li2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
_HTML;
}
echo '</div>', PHP_EOL;
```

To make it flexible as asked in the comments, here is another approach. Assuming having always a headline and a flexible amount of li.

```
$copy = $data;
while(count($copy[0]))
{
    $rowdata = [];
    foreach($copy as &$value) {
        $rowdata[] = array_shift($value);
    }
    unset($value);
    $headline = array_shift($rowdata);
    $li = '';
    foreach($rowdata as $value) {
        $li .= "<li class=\"bg-primary text-white\">$value</li>\n";
    }

    echo <<<"_HTML"
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h3 class="text-primary text-center">$headline</h3>
        <ul class="list-box">
            $li
        </ul>
    </div>
_HTML;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If there are more arrays how do we do then? Can we fetch all arrays excluding the first "array_shift($copy[0]);" and put all other arrays into a variable $li so there is no $li1, $li2, $li3 etc. This might solve my problem.

Comment: Shift does the trick, that it gets very first array value independent of a numeric or indexed key. That solution fits perfectly your provided data. If you have another structure, another solution must come.

Comment: I came up with another idea, hope it fits your needs. Answer got an Update.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You solved my problem. I liked the first answer of yours tho.

Comment: How do we pass class "bg-warning" and "bg-blue" to li for 2nd and 3rd columns?

Comment: That's another question, but easy also. Because it is already marked as correct, here's a pastebin. https://pastebin.com/1btWw0aQ

Comment: If there are not as many classes as li items, you would get an undefined index error. I've fixed that updating line 15.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your array is not suitable for what you want to do. So there is 2 options left; in first scenario you have to change your array structure first (make your looping array more suitable for your need by changing key-value of your array), second scenario is a little bir static solution but maybe it solve your problem and here it is;

```
<?php 
$your_array = array(
    0 => array(
        'label_01' => 'heading 01:',
        'label_02' => 'heading 02:',
        'label_03' => 'heading 03:',
        ),
    1 => array(
        'label_01' => 'item 01',
        'label_02' => 'item 02',
        'label_03' => 'item 03',
        ),
    2 => array(
        'label_01' => 'item 001',
        'label_02' => 'item 002',
        'label_03' => 'item 003',
        ),
); //this is your sample array :P  

?>
<div class="row">
<?php 
$headers = $your_array[0]; // fetch the headers first... because our main loop is headers in your case...
$items = $your_array[1]; // fetch the items... we do it because your array is unordered for your needs...
$sub_items = $your_array[2]; // fetch the sub_items... we do it because your array is unordered for your needs...

foreach($headers as $key => $val) {
?>
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <h3 class="text-primary text-center"><?php echo $val; ?></h3>
    <ul class="list-box">
        <?php 
        foreach($items as $key2 => $val2) { 
            if($key2 == $key) {
        ?>
        <li class="bg-primary text-white"><?php echo $val2; ?></li>
        <?php 
            }
        } 

        foreach($sub_items as $key2 => $val2) { 
            if($key2 == $key) {
        ?>
        <li class="bg-primary text-white"><?php echo $val2; ?></li>
        <?php 
            }
        } 
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If there are more arrays how do we do then? Can we fetch all arrays excluding the first "$your_array[0]". This might solve my problem.

Comment: yeah, I will try.

Comment: if your datas prepending all the same the answer is yes. Always you have to use $your_array[0] for fetching all headers